# django form choicefield update after every query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

i have created a webapp. this is how it works

1. user inputs a number mapped with a product
2. csv file corresponding to that product gets downloaded
3. you are presented with a form which contains one property name
   along with choices available for that property

issue i am facing is, this whole process works for first search only
after that whenever user enters any different number for any other product
ideally choicefield in the form should get updated, but it  dont get updated,

i have deployed this app on heroku,if i restart all dynos this fixes the
problem but just for time being. i mean for only one search, again same
problem happens

link to the app:
https://abcd4.herokuapp.com/

link to the code:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zlKowvcpK5NOnmAZFstDPC1oWTH97WmX?usp=sharing

problem is not about the deployed platform i.e heroku
i faced same issue when i ran app on localhost
on localhost also restarting app solved the problem

```
forms2.py

from django import forms
from django.core import validators

def mergefunction(s1,s2):
    merged = []
    for i in range(0, len(s1)):
        tup = (s1[i],s2[i])
        merged.append(tup)
    return merged

class GeeksForm(forms.Form): 
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    filename =  r"downloaded1.csv"
    data = open(filename, encoding = "utf8")
    csv_data = csv.reader(data)
    data_lines = list(csv_data)
    total_row  = (len(data_lines))
    total_col = 0
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in data_lines[0]:
        if(total_col>=14):
            list1.append(i)
            list2.append(i)
        total_col = total_col + 1
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    property_dic = {}

    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        key = list1[i]
        saved_column = df[list1[i]]
        saved_column = set(saved_column)
        s1 = list(saved_column)
        s2 = list(saved_column)
        merged = mergefunction(s1,s2)
        value = merged
        value = tuple(value)
        property_dic[key] = value


    k = (len(list1))    

    i = 0
    if i < k:
        key1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices = property_dic[list1[i]] )
    i = i + 1









view.py


def form_name_view(request):
    from . import forms2
    from .scrap2 import fun3

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms2.GeeksForm(request.POST)
    
        if form.is_valid():
                print("VALID")
                lenoflist = fun3()
                lenoflist = 2
                i = 0
                listofdata = []
                if i < lenoflist:
                    data = form.cleaned_data['key1']
                    listofdata.append(data)
                i = i+1
            
                return finalfun(request,listofdata)

    else:
        form = forms2.GeeksForm()


    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    filename =  r"downloaded1.csv"
    data = open(filename, encoding = "utf8")
    csv_data = csv.reader(data)
    data_lines = list(csv_data)
    total_row  = (len(data_lines))
    total_col = 0
    list1 = []
    for i in data_lines[0]:
        if(total_col>=14):
            list1.append(i)
        total_col = total_col + 1

    context = {
        'form' : form,
            "List" : list1[0],

    }
    return render(request,'firstapp/form_page2.html',context)
```

Comment: don't link to code. Write it in the question.

Comment: i have written code in the question @paul

Comment: break each piece of code down into a method that does something specific and then returns a result. But in general I suggest you do a few more form tutorials. It's hard to work out what your problem is from this code.

Comment: I will try to explain what I want to do, I am creating choicefield options from a column of a CSV file , this file will be different for different products, when user visits site for first time he gets choicefield options corresponding to correct product but on second visit onwards even if user select any other product, choicefield options of previous product are shown.

Comment: write some tests....